# How do I get Jenkins to correctly map the user's display name and email address?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins instance connected to a directory service for authentication. I configured the display name and email attributes. I have a build checking out a Subversion repository over HTTP (via Apache), which authenticates with the same LDAP.

I expected Jenkins to pull the user from the commit metadata (the `svn:author` property), map the display name to show in the Changes screen, and map the email address for sending build notifications.

I'm having trouble with both:

1. Jenkins only shows the user's display name after they log in once. For example, my user name is `anthony.mastrean` and my display name is `Anthony Mastrean`. My changes were linked as `anthony.mastrean` until I logged in.
2. Jenkins **never** pulls the email address. It's has this in my user configuration and in the log for the email notifier:

   ```
   anthony.mastrean@548b7ffa-d19c-4046-8715-d3a94a596a03
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration used to build from a Git-Svn bridge repository. We didn't create that bridge with an authors mapping file. This is the mess that Git makes of the user name to satisfy it's own committer/author email address metadata.

```
anthony.mastrean@548b7ffa-d19c-4046-8715-d3a94a596a03
```

Jenkins was happy to use this information (pulled from the revision metadata) for our users. Maybe or maybe not because we hadn't configured LDAP yet (we did that later).

Blah.

---

Oh, an actual answer: we just wiped out the junk email addresses listed for each user and Jenkins happily pulled it from LDAP next time.